# Java 8 Map Reduce on HashMap as lambda

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I have a `String` and want to replace some words within. I have a `HashMap` where the key is the placeholder to be replaced and the value  the word to replace it. Here is my old-school code:

```
  private String replace(String text, Map<String, String> map) {
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      text = text.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return text;
  }
```

Is there a way to write this code as a lambda expression?

I tried `entrySet().stream().map(...).reduce(...).apply(...);` but couldn't make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing to be weary of, is short placeholders contained within larger ones. Make sure that your placeholders are sorted by length, longest first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don’t think that you should try to find a simpler or shorter solution, but rather think about the semantics and efficiency of your approach.

You are iterating over a map which likely has no specified iteration order (like `HashMap`) and performing one replacement after another, using the result of a replacement as input to the next, potentially missing matches due to previously applied replaces or replacing contents within the replacements.

Even if we assume that you are passing in a map whose keys and values have no interference, this approach is very inefficient. Note further that `replaceAll` will interpret the arguments as regular expressions.

If we assume that no regular expressions are intended, we can clear ambiguities between keys by sorting them by length, so that longer keys are attempted first. Then, a solution doing a single replacement operation may look like:

```
private static String replace(String text, Map<String, String> map) {
    if(map.isEmpty()) return text;
    String pattern = map.keySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed())
        .map(Pattern::quote)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
    if(!m.find()) return text;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(map.get(m.group())));
       while(m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

<sup>starting with Java 9, you can use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` here</sup>

If you test it with

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("f", "F");
map.put("foo", "bar");
map.put("b", "B");
System.out.println(replace("foo, bar, baz", map));
```

you’ll get

```
bar, Bar, Baz
```

demonstrating that replacing `foo` gets precedence over replacing `f` and the `b` within its replacement `bar` is not replaced.

A different thing would be if you *want* to replace matches within replacements again. In that case, you would need either, a mechanism to control the order or implement a repeated replacement that will only return when there are no matches anymore. Of course, the latter requires care to provide replacements which always will converge to a result eventually.

E.g.

```
private static String replaceRepeatedly(String text, Map<String, String> map) {
    if(map.isEmpty()) return text;
    String pattern = map.keySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed())
        .map(Pattern::quote)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
    if(!m.find()) return text;
    StringBuffer sb;
    do {
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        do m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(map.get(m.group())));
           while(m.find());
        m.appendTail(sb);
    } while(m.reset(sb).find());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "e1");
map.put("e", "o2");
map.put("o", "x3");
System.out.println(replaceRepeatedly("foo, bar, baz", map));
```

```
fx3x3, bx321r, bx321z
```

Answer (score 3):

Few improvements to @RavindraRanwala 's code.

```
    String replacement = Stream.of(text.split("\\b"))
            .map(token -> map.getOrDefault(token, token))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

1) Use `Map.getOrDefault` from Java 8

2) Split by "\b" to support any delimiter of the words, not only space character

Comment: There is also `Pattern.compile("\\b").splitAsStream(text)` - that way the precompiled Pattern could be reused, and the creation of the array avoided

Answer (score 2):

You can use for each loop as following:

```
  private String replace(String text, Map<String, String> map) {
      final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
      map.forEach((k,v)->replaceAll(sb, k, v));
      return sb.toString();
  }
```

Replace all method can be defined as:

```
public static void replaceAll(StringBuilder builder, String from, String to){
    int index = builder.indexOf(from);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        builder.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
        index += to.length(); // Move to the end of the replacement
        index = builder.indexOf(from, index);
    }
}
```

You can also use `StringBuffer` if you are using multi threading.

Comment: "text" is a string which is immutable, so it must be saved in the variable "text" again, but that is not possbile because text isn't final.

Comment: See the edits. You can use StringBuffer which is mutable.

Comment: @Kaushal28 StringBuffer doesn't have `replaceAll` method

Answer (score 1):

For real-life purposes, your non-stream code is just fine.  As a fun exercise, you can represent each mapping as a `Function<String,String>` and reduce on the functions:

```
Function<String,String> combined = map.entrySet().stream()
        .reduce(
                Function.identity(),
                (f, e) -> x -> f.apply(x).replaceAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
                Function::andThen
        );

return combined.apply(text);
```